# Laravel mix keep creating minified file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-mix

When I use laravel mix  with these commands `npm run dev` or `npm run watch`, they still create a minified file for the Highcharts library. How can I get the unminified version at least in dev ?

Here my files

**webpack.mix.js**

```
let mix = require('laravel-mix');
mix.js('resources/assets/js/app.js', 'public/js');
mix.autoload({  // or Mix.autoload() ?
    'jquery': ['$', 'window.jQuery', 'jQuery']
});
```

**app.js**

```
...
import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts';
// import Highcharts from 'highcharts/highcharts.src.js'; // not working
// import Highcharts from 'highcharts/js/highcharts.src.js'; // not working
import HighchartsMore from 'highcharts/highcharts-more.src.js'; // works
HighchartsMore(Highcharts);
...
import HighchartsVue from 'highcharts-vue';
Vue.use(HighchartsVue);
```

Comment: During building you are also getting source maps so browser (like Chrome) can *unminify* the js/css on the fly in the development tools, thats why there is no option to **not minify**.

Comment: I have the opposite problem: it never minifies.  Laravel mix is just broken in so many ways.